# Slow Application (Monitored)

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, networking, ms-access-2007, prtg

Good Day:

We are currently running an access 2007 ADP that acts as a cashiering system for our organization. The application experiences lag spikes causing it to become unbearably slow and sometimes crash.

The steps I have taken to monitor the application include:

1. PRTG monitoring for network traffic (traffic is normal and bandwidth is more than enough
   to handle upload/download.
2. Database Monitoring to track query throughput and resource usage (results are normal)
3. End User application monitoring: Includes the use of task manager and ExtraHop

Any suggestions on what other steps I can take to monitor and determine the cause of these lags. Unfortunately, I am beginning to think that the cause is at the application code level and the software may need to be replaced. Hopefully I am wrong though.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Using variety of application performance monitoring (APM) tools you typically can see how and where your application is using it's time which could lead you to the source of the issue that cause it to run slow or crash. 
You can check this list:
[10 best application performance management tools](http://www.business2community.com/brandviews/getapp/10-best-application-performance-management-tools-2014-01032374)